# Mobile devices horizontal scroll and images not centering

Tags: css, mobile

I'm working on a website and I have 2 problems with it for mobile devices. The problems may be linked.

If you go to this website on mobile - [website](http://wizard4socialmedia.com)

You will see that even though there's no element overflowing, the page can be scrolled left and right. I can't figure out why. I want the page to be stable, no left/right scrolling, as there's nothing to see on the right side.

The website only has 4 pages, but this happens on each page. But from what I can tell the width is 100%, so it shouldn't be happening.

And on the "**ABOUT**" page there are 3 images on the right, and for some reason they don't want to be centered when the site is viewed on mobile devices. They just overflow there.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Page is scrollable because of 'Contact us' section. You can set `overflow-x : hidden ` on body, but that will just hide the problem

Comment: What do you mean the 'Contact us' section? The contact button on the top navbar isn't even visible on mobile when the page loads. Can you be more specific, which contact us section is causing the problem? Do you mean the contact us page?

Comment: Nope I mean on page section below 'About us' ( when in mobile view) there is PayPal picture in it. It's on every page. It's at the bottom of the page (almost) .

Comment: That's not it man. I removed that entire div from the footer, and it's still happening.

Comment: let me see , just a sec

Comment: Okay man, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180138/discussion-between-marko-mackic-and-overloard).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. Marko Mackic pointed out the logo was too wide, and helped me fix it.